# Redirection in MVC with only one segment (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/tester)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am stuck in a situation where I want to generate a url like www.so.com/ASXDH - So this will redirect to the specific action of my controller.

I have tried many ways like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                  "redirector",  // Route name
                  "{url}", // URL with parameters
                  new { controller = "Home", action = "Redirector", url = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );
```

But it doesn't work.

I am working on my assignment of URL shortner. So when I generate a short URL of specific URL lets say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask is short to http://so.com/asdf. So when this short URL gets a hit my controller will redirect user to the actual URL

Hope some one helps.

Answer (score 0):

First thing for routing to

```
routes.MapRoute(
                  "Home",  // Route name
                  "{ASXDH }", // URL with parameters
                  new { controller = "ASDXH", action = "Index", url = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );
```

For URL shorten you need to map that URl to the default URL in the routecollection

```
routes.MapRoute(
                  "Home",  // Route name
                  "{Home/Index/stackoverflow.com}", // URL with parameters
                  new { controller = "ASDXH", action = "Index", url = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );
```

OR you can do this way too

```
return RedirectToAction("Actionname");
```